# Swap even odd indices in a java int array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am trying to swap numbers in int array according to even and odd indices.
So far,
I was able to work out how to target even and odd indices but,
then because of nested for loops I am not able to print all the elements in one array.
Here is my code -

```
public class SwapIndexes {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        int temp;
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j += 2) {
            for (int k = 1; k < arr.length; k += 2) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[k];
                arr[k] = temp;
                System.out.print(arr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code gives `124312531` as output for `arr[k]` and gives `246124312` as output for `arr[j]`. I want the output to be

> 2,1,4,3,6,5

Comment: Why do you have two loops? You only need one loop

Comment: What is the logic here, specifically with regard to even and odd indices?  Also, if your input array only has 6 items, how can the same array have 9 items in it after the swap?

Comment: please show in code..i thought 2 loops would be required since 2 types of indexes

Comment: You are not printing the resulting array but a cell at some point. Print the array after both loops to see the result. I don't understand what you are trying to do so I can't add anything. You might want to propose a [mcve] to explain the logic

Comment: the "logic" if you choose to call it that is a combination of j=0, k=1 and both += 2.

Comment: I want the output to be

2,1,4,3,6,5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't understand why you have two loops. You only need one since you need to browse the array only once. Here is the code with one loop: `j` will have all the odd indexes and then you switch `j-1` and `j`.
Since no specification is given about the behavior of an array with an odd number of elements, in that case it doesn't modify the last value. If needed, you can throw an exception.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
        int temp;
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j += 2) {
                temp = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: in that case leave the last element untouched.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson : funny, I tested it with 7 elements and it worked just fine...
Have you even tried the code before telling me what would happen?

Comment: @Ricola I accepted your answer. Thank You. but could you show what to do if the array contains an odd number of elements and leave the last element untouched.

Comment: Initially it appears as though it would throw a NPE, but if you look closely it will never index past the length (i.e. Array of length 6 will only index to j=5 and Array of length 7 will also only index to index j=5)

Comment: hmm..got it now. So no need to worry about odd number of elements in array

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why you have use two loop because the idea was there.

Remove the second loop, set `k` to `j + 1` and the logic is here (commented the code that you don't need.

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j += 2) {
   //for (int k = 1; k < arr.length; k += 2) {
   int k = j + 1;
       temp = arr[j];
       arr[j] = arr[k];
       arr[k] = temp;
       //System.out.print(arr[k]);
   //}
}
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Now, you need to prevent exception to occurs for uneven length.
I like to simple use a slightly different loop :

```
for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j += 2) {
   int k = j - 1;
   ...
}
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

All you have to do is check if there is at least 2 cells, which make sense if you want to reverse an array like this

```
if(arr.length < 2)
     return;
```

Test 1:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>   [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]

Test 2:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
>   [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7]